# Best way to create SQL user with read only permissions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the best-practice to create a read-only user for a specific database?

I created a new user and granted the db_datareader role, however, this user still has access to the master db and other system databases. is that ok? or should i deny access on some system tables/databases as well to make it more secure?

Thanks.

---

Ok, so if i create a new user, will he have any more default permissions i have to deny?
if i do 
~create login
~create user for login..
~grant EXECUTE for user

will the user only have EXECUTE permissions or will he have additional permissions as well for the active database?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe the user can view other database in the object explorer too.

```
CREATE LOGIN me with password = 'me', check_policy = off

sp_changedbowner 'me'
GO

USE MASTER
GO


DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO me
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use denywrite as an role option. The user has to "see" the master, because the master contains the list of databases that he will enventually connect to, but he will only have guest privalages there. You can then deny access to other specific databases. AFAIK he does not need to see tempdb or msdb as its the SQL engine that accesses these